# Cannot invoke 'setData' with an argument list of type '([String : Any], completion: ((Error?) -> Void)?)'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a sign up method via Google Cloud Firestore for my app and I'm receiving the following error in the link below:

[Expected an argument list of type '([String : Any], completion: ((Error?) -> Void)?)'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz8vc.png)

I'm new to Swift & iOS Development. Could someone please help explain the issue here?

I builds successfully now that I edited to:

```
 guard let userId = authResult?.user else { return }
        let userData: [String: Any] = [
            "firstName" : "",
            "User ID" : userId,
            "dateCreated" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            ]
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document("one").setData(userData) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

but it gives me the runtime error: 
[terminating with uncaught exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqD96.png)

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1):

This is `setData` syntax here in [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData([
    "name": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "country": "USA"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't set the data correctly it seems. So I could've done something like let userData: [String: Any] = [   "first name" : firstName, "dateCreated" : FieldValue.serverTimeStamp, etc??
 =